# iPhone apps and state aware web connections

Tags: iphone, json

I'm working on an interface for an existing web application that will allow iPhone and other mobile clients.

I have started implement a JSON API and I need to give some detailed specificaitions for the App to an iPhone developer.

What I am curious about is whether other developers are using session data in their JSON / mobile client communications.

Do the common url grabbing libraries of iPhones (and other mobile devices) mimic a browser's cookie handling?

Can someone suggest what libraries might be used to achieve this? Are there any online tutorials or blog entries that outline state based web connectivity in an iPhone app?

Answer (score 0):

I've used ASIHTTP (http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) and JSONFramework (http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) to achieve this.

Both very good libraries that are easy to work with.